# How do I pass arguments to a PL/SQL script on command line with SQLPLUS?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

How do I pass arguments to a PL/SQL script on command line with SQLPLUS?   I can call my PL/SQL script like so, but the script requires arguments in order for it to succeed.  How can I run sqlplus.exe so that I can pass arguments to the script?

```
@ECHO off
// where HOST030 is a tnsnames alias to a machine, port, and instance    
sqlplus.exe MYUSER/mypassword@HOST030 < refreshDataOnOracle.sql    
pause
```

I tried to search for the answer but couldn't find an "argument example" anywhere for SQLPLUS.  I suspect it would be a similar method of using the SQL*Plus "START" command?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Firstly, you will need to invoke your script like so:

```
sqlplus.exe MYUSER/mypassword@HOST030 @refreshDataOnOracle.sql foo bar
```

Instead of the OS redirection you will use the "@" symbol to indicate the file name to execute. You will also supply the script parameters on the command line. In the script you will refer to the parameters using `&1`, `&2` etc.

```
update mytable set mycol = '&2' where myid = '&1';
```

which will translate into

```
update mytable set mycol = 'bar' where myid = 'foo';
```

Comment: Thanks.  That was it.  It sounds like the '@' character is an alias for "START".

Comment: @ChadD see `sqlplus` [`spool`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve043.htm#i2683777)-command.

Comment: Not sure but can't you "replace" the `&` with another delimiter by setting `set define` ?

Comment: I also want to add that do not set this in your SQL "SET DEFINE OFF" if you do that then this wont work.

Answer (score 5):

If you want log the run of sqlplus, you can use this syntax:

```
sqlplus.exe MYUSER/mypassword@HOST030 @refreshDataOnOracle.sql foo bar  >> log.log
```