# How to filter your sql query using declared parameters in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a Oracle SQL script and would like to pass input parameter to the script for execution.
How would I achieve this?

Say I have date parameter testdate. This is how we do it in sql server

```
declare @testdate as date

select * from test where testdate=@testdate
```

Basically I have set of sql statements in a block which needs to be executed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I pass arguments to a PL/SQL script on command line with SQLPLUS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18620893/how-do-i-pass-arguments-to-a-pl-sql-script-on-command-line-with-sqlplus)

Comment: do you want to concatenate previous sql query with new one .....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass it as an argument to the SQL script and invoke it in SQL*Plus.

For example,

I have a script **emp.sql** which looks like -

`select ename from emp where empno=&1`

Now, I will invoke it in **SQL*Plus** passing the empno as an argument.

```
SQL> @D:\emp.sql 7369
old   1: select ename from emp where empno=&1
new   1: select ename from emp where empno=7369

ENAME
----------
SMITH

SQL>
```

Similarly, for a date argument -

```
SQL> @D:\emp.sql sysdate
old   1: select ename from emp where hiredate<=&1
new   1: select ename from emp where hiredate<=sysdate

ENAME
----------
SMITH
ALLEN
WARD
JONES
MARTIN
BLAKE
CLARK
SCOTT
KING
TURNER
ADAMS

ENAME
----------
JAMES
FORD
MILLER

14 rows selected.

SQL>
```

For string type, you need to have single-quotation marks. For example -

```
SQL> @D:\emp.sql SCOTT
old   1: select empno from emp where ename='&1'
new   1: select empno from emp where ename='SCOTT'

     EMPNO
----------
      7788

SQL>
```